# Post a iframe form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe with a form inside a modal box and I want the modal box to have a submit button. On clicking submit of the submit button I want the iframe form to be submitted.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick = "window.frames[0].document.form[0].submit();"

if it is submit button, call this on onsubmit event and return false.